# Лишние пиксели в header

Tags: html, css

Назначил блоку в хедере размер 100 на 100 пкс и задал флоат право.
Но на сайте появились лишние 10 пикселей. Как их убрать и от куда они появились?

Ссылкa  на код http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKqjGK

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}


a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

li {
 list-style: none;
}

body , html {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #dcdad9 ;
 width: 100%;
}

header {
 display: block;
 min-width: 1270px;
 background-color: #070607;
 height: 100px;
}

header .logo {
 float: left;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}

header .logo img {
 width: 62px;
 height: 72px;
 margin: 15px;

}

header .cart {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right:0px;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color:#fff;
 box-sizing: border-box;

}

header .cart img {
 width: 63px;
 height: 35px;
 margin: 25px;
}

header .main-menu ul {
 padding-top: 45px;
 padding-left: 225px;
}

header .main-menu li{
 display: inline;
 margin-right: 50px;

 
}

header .main-menu  a {
 color: #716c6a;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="images/LogoF.png" alt="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="main-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#HOME"> HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#PRODUCT-PAGES"> PRODUCT pages</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#PRODUCT-LISTING"> product listing</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#PAGES">  pages</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#DRESSES"> dresses</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#OUTWEAR"> outwear</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="cart">
    <img src="Images/cart.png">
  </div>
</header>

<section>
  <main>

  </main>

  <aside>
    <div>
      <a href="#search"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#account"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#settings"></a>
    </div>
  </aside>
</section>
```

Comment: не вижу ваш `float` и где эти лишние пиксели? если речь о блоке Cart, то у него ширина родителя для картинки и ширина картинки не соответствуют - либо поправьте ширину, либо отступы вокруг картинки, и "лишнее" место возле картинки пропадёт

Answer (score 1):

у header задайте

position: relative;
overflow: hidden;

Так же советую изучить поведение absolute в зависимости от position родителя.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть в высоте линий дело попробуйте в

```
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
```

поставить 0

```
body {
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header .cart img {
    width: 63px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 25px
}
```

width( 63 pixel ) + margin( 25 pixel *2 ) = 113 pixels

как-то так, кажеться, считается при box-sizing: border-box